# How to protect my form input field data from a user to changes in the console?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I want to take some of my card's data to the next page.
But if i want to send data through the form, the user can change it from the console.

If I hide the input field then it can still be changed through the console.

```
<form action="{{url('/checkout')}}" method="post">
    @csrf

      <input type="hidden" name="total_amount3" value="{{ ($subTotal-($subTotal*$coupon_amount)/100) }}">
      <button class="site-btn btn-full" type="submit">Proceed to checkout</button>
     </form>
```

How can I send my data on the next page without change by the user?

Comment: After input is entered by user (`onblur`) create hash of the input (such as `md5`) , on next page compute the hash again and compare that both hashes match

Comment: Using PHP [$_SESSION](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) would allow you to access the data on the second page without allowing a user to modify it via the console.  Just make sure to clear the sesson after you use it on the second page.

Comment: Thanks, @aditya  But if the user turns off JavaScript lode on the browser?

Comment: `<noscript>This website does not work without JavaScript! Please enable it to continue</noscript>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the data is in the frontend, there's nothing you can do, the user can change it by inspecting or through the console

Move your variable to the backend

```php
public function checkout(Request $request)
{
   $subTotal = $request->subTotal; // Or calculate it here from the products in the cart or whatever
   $request->request->add(['subTotal' => ($subTotal-($subTotal*$coupon_amount)/100)]);
   // Rest of code goes here...
}
```